# Error 2448 "cannot assign a value" on VBA Form Close event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an ordinary form (not modal) based on an ordinary query.  During the `Close()` event, when I write an update to the `TaxFinal` field of the record, I receive an error:

```
runtime error 2448: You cannot assign a value to this object.
```

While the form is open, I can update the field by typing in a new value.  It isn't a calculated field.

This form has a fair amount of VBA automation.  So I stripped away most of the code and ran a decompile followed by a compile.  Here is what is left:

```
Option Compare Database:    Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Form!boxTaxFinal = 0.11
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
    Me.Form!boxTaxFinal = 0.12  ' <--- ERROR 2448
End Sub
```

As you could expect, these entries in the Immediate window also fail:

```
Me.Form!boxTaxFinal = 0.12  ' <--- ERROR 2448
Me.boxTaxFinal = 0.12       ' <--- ERROR 2448
```

I can't write to other fields, either, so it isn't a naming snafu.

I understand I could choose a different form event such as `AfterUpdate()` but I think `Close()` works as well for my purposes.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Ah.  I've used `Form_Close()` where I need `Form_BeforeUpdate()'.  Thank you.  Please present as an answer, or I will close this out some other way (but I think best as an answer so I can find this NEXT time I'm stumped, ha ha).

Comment: At 58k, most things do.  Hang in there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data-bound controls are not available for editing after Form Unload.  I'm unsure whether they are *always* unavailable or just not reliably available.  Either way, Form Close happens after Form Unload, and at that stage you can't access data-bound controls at all.

Choose a different form event, such as Before Update, to run your code.